# Write file specific folder inside localFolder

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I'm trying to write an image file to the localFolder storage.  I want to write it specifically to the `images/heroes/` folder inside the localFolder.  Is there some way to do this with my existing code?

```
return WinJS.xhr({ url: fileToDownloadURL, responseType: 'blob' }).then(
   function (response) {
      var input = response.response.msDetachStream();
      var filename = 'ms-appx:///local/images/heroes/image_name.png';

      Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync(filename,
      Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(
         function (file) {
            return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite).then(
               function (output) {
                  return Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(input, output).then(
                     function () {
                        output.flushAsync().then(function () {
                           input.close();
                           output.close();
                     });
                });
          });
     }
   }
)};
```

I get this error message:

`0x8007007b - JavaScript runtime error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

`WinRT information: The specified name (ms-appx:///local/images/heroes/image_name.png) contains one or more invalid characters.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.  For anyone wondering, you can call

`getFolderAsync('SomeFolderName')`

from the

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder`

instance.  `getFolderAsync()` is like any promise function and will return with an error if the folder does not exist.  From there you can run

`createFolderAsync('SomeFolderName')`

to create the folder, and then continue what you were doing.  In my case it was better to create a function like `writeFileAsync()` and then call it depending on whether or not the folder exists first.

Keep in mind `getFolderAsync()` can only get one folder at a time, so something like

`getFolderAsync('along/list/of/folders')`

won't work.  You'll have to chain together the `getFolderAsync()` calls together, I believe (correct me if I'm wrong!).